# bootstrap How to delete hover on drop down menu in mobile view?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know there is no hover in mobile view. but it's better to delete hover when I test mobile size from my browser.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sports</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Basketball</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tennis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">volleyball</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">DEVELOPMENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OUR TEAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

I am using this code to make drop down menu only appear on hover in size > 767px.

```
/* drop down menu hover*/
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
/* close drop down menu on focus */
.open>.dropdown-menu{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to delete hover on drop down menu in mobile view?

Comment: Why do you need to delete it when it won't action anyway?

Comment: `@media only screen and (min-width: 766px) {
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;    
    }
}`

Comment: @Autista_z it should be `display:none` :)

Comment: @Katana No. I am making the oposite. I am displaying it only if the width is more than 766px; I have min-width, you have max-width.

Comment: @Autista_z sorry but the thought is the same with my answer :). Your targeting the greater value im doing the opposite

Comment: @Katana of course. Its the same. In my sollution he have to edit his code, in your he have to add your code.

Comment: @Autista_z yes your right it's his choice, maybe he is asleep now

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Media queries : 
Specify the size of your target device.
So in your example, i assume that screens less than 767 is for device so we will set this value as max-width.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* drop down menu hover for device */
  ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;    
   }
}
```